# Can virtualbox monitor what you do when you use it in connection to the Internet?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, malware

Can virtualbox monitor what you do when you use it in connection to the Internet? Is there any evidence this is not technically possible (any link available)? Or is it just our trust in the software developers

Thanks.

Comment: That is the function of a packet sniffer that you should be able to install on the VM.  Typically a virtualizing appliction just provides Internet to the guest machine and does not monitor it.

Comment: Could it, sure, why would it though, loss of VM performance, gov't regulations, lawsuits, etc, and VirtualBox is open-source, you can check yourself. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Source_code_organization